# Generate N "equally spaced" vectors on the unit sphere

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors

I want to generate a list of vectors $\{\mathbf{v}_i\}, i\in[1,N]$ such that

$$\mathbf{v}_i\cdot\mathbf{v}_i = 1, \forall i$$

$$\mathbf{v}_i\cdot\mathbf{v}_j = \cos\theta, \forall i\neq j$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf{v}_i = 0$$

$$\mathbf{v}_1=(1,0,0)$$

$$\mathbf{v}_2=(\cos\theta,0,\sin\theta)$$

For $N=2$, we have $\mathbf{v}_1=(1,0,0), \mathbf{v}_2=(-1,0,0), \theta=\pi$.

For $N=3$, we have $\mathbf{v}_1=(1,0,0), \mathbf{v}_2=(-1/2,0,\sqrt{3}/2), \mathbf{v}_2=(-1/2,0,-\sqrt{3}/2),\theta=2\pi/3$.

etc.

I would like to be able to generate this list of vectors for arbitrary $N$. I can do it by hand, but I want to add this to some python code. I tried to come up with an iterative way of doing it, but I lose track of all the vector components I have to solve for pretty quickly. What is the simplest way to do this?

$N$ is not going to be huge -- let's say $N=30$ at most. Because of this, and because this generation will be done once in my code, I'm not super worried about the performance of the python code that I will implement.

Comment: As stated, you want the $\theta$ to be the same for every pair of vectors.  I believe this is impossible for $N>4$.  Consider the case of $N=6$, where I imagine you would be happy with the vertices of a regular octahedron.  But this has $v_i\cdot v_j = 0$ for some $i,j$, and $v_i\cdot v_j = -1$ for others.

Comment: [This page on spherical codes by N.J.A. Sloane](http://neilsloane.com/packings/) provides specific solutions to the problem of selecting points on a sphere such that the separation between any two points is maximized, for the $N$ you want. [The actual solutions for $\Bbb R^3$ are here](http://neilsloane.com/packings/dim3/). [This Math SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4680506/25554) discusses the case of very large $N$.

Comment: To read Sloane's solutions, see for example  [the packing of six points](http://neilsloane.com/packings/dim3/pack.3.6.txt).  The file contains 18 numbers, which are successively the $x,y,z$ coordinates of the six points.  The last two points $\langle 0, 0, 1\rangle$ and $\langle 0,0,-1\rangle$ are the poles, and the other four points are equally spaced around the equator.

Comment: @MJD I see. If I try to solve by components, at $N=5$, I run into an issue. By definition, for $i>2$, $\mathbf{v}_i\cdot\mathbf{v}_1=\cos\theta$, $\mathbf{v}_i\cdot\mathbf{v}_2=\cos\theta$, which means that the $z$-component of $\mathbf{v}_i$ is $(\cos\theta-\cos\theta^2)/\sin\theta$ and the $y$-component is $\pm \sqrt{1-\cos\theta^2-v_{iz}^2}$. We can't generate 5 vectors this way.

Comment: Right, I don't think you can get five vectors that have the property you stated, or indeed any $N>4$.  In the $N=5$ case I believe the best you can do is two poles and then three equally spaced around the equator.  (That is, a triangular dipyramid.) The Sloane numbers seem to agree with this.

Comment: If you really want to code this, one way is with a sort of physics simulation.  Pretend that the points are charged particles.  Put them on the sphere at random.  Simulate the repulsive forces on the particles: if two particles are close together, they will repel until the whole system is in equilibrium.  When it settles down, that is your answer.  (Not necessarily the _optimal_ answer, but at least locally optimal.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to handle the problem is to let $V$ be a matrix whose columns are the desired vectors. Then the Gram matrix $M=V^\top V$ satisfies $M_{ij}=\mathbf{v}_i\cdot \mathbf{v}_j$, so the constraints specify $M_{ij}=\cos\theta$ if $i\neq j$ and $1$ otherwise. The assumption that $\sum_{i}\mathbf{v}_i=0$ further amounts to the claim that $Vu=0$ where $u$ is a column vector of 1s. But then $Mu=V^\top Vu=0$, whereas one can show that the characteristic polynomial of $M$ is $$\det(M-\lambda I_N)=(1-\cos\theta-\lambda)^{N-1} (1+(N-1)\cos\theta-\lambda).$$ So if we assume the vectors are not collinear, we *must* have $\cos\theta=-1/(N-1)$ for $M$ to have a zero eigenvalue. The determinant furthermore shows that $M$ will have $N-1$ eigenvectors of eigenvalue $\lambda=1-\cos\theta=N/(N-1)$. This gives us $N-1$ of the needed vectors, with the last vector being deduced from $\sum_i \mathbf{v}_i=0$. Hence the $N$ vectors must be at least $(N-1)$-dimensional, e.g., we must go up to at least dimension 29 if we want 30 such vectors.